# Bootstrap drop down with angular 7 not working well

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm making a drop-down language switch list for my Angular app, some time the menu does not work when navigate from component to other unless I refresh the page, and I do not understand why !

this is the html code :

```
  <!-- language -->
      <div class="traduction">
        <ul>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <img style="width:30px; height:30px;" class="img-profile rounded-circle" [src]="translate.currentLang == 'fr' ? '../../../assets/img/fr.png' : '../../../assets/img/ar.png'">
            </a>
            <div class="lang-menu dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="changeLang('fr')">
                <i class="far fa-flag fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                Français
              </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="changeLang('ar')">
                <i class="far fa-flag fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                عربي
              </a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
 <!-- end language -->
```

the drop down is on the auth and navbar components, when navigate from auth to app home the dropdown does not work unless I refresh the page, on logout also  !

I'm using angular 7 with bootstrap 4